# Time complexity of merge sort: function appears to be called 2*n-1 times rather than O(log n) times

Tags: python, time-complexity, mergesort

I'm teaching a coding class and need an intuitive and obvious way to explain the time complexity of merge sort. I tried including a print statement at the start of my merge_sort() function, anticipating that the print statement would execute O(log n) times. However, as best as I can tell, it executes 2*n-1 times instead (Python code below):

**merge_sort() function:**

```
def merge_sort(my_list):
    print("hi") #prints 2*n-1 times??
    if(len(my_list) <= 1):
        return
    mid = len(my_list)//2
    l = my_list[:mid]
    r = my_list[mid:]
    merge_sort(l)
    merge_sort(r)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    while(i < len(l) or j < len(r)):
        #print("hey") #prints nlogn times as expected
        if(i >= len(l)):
            my_list[k] = r[j]
            j += 1
        elif(j >= len(r)):
            my_list[k] = l[i]
            i += 1
        elif(l[i] < r[j]):
            my_list[k] = l[i]
            i += 1
        elif(l[i] > r[j]):
            my_list[k] = r[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1
```

**Driver code:**

```
#print("Enter a list")
my_list = list(map(int, input().split()))
#print("Sorted list:")
#merge_sort(my_list)
print(my_list)
```

**Input:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

**Expected output:**

```
hi
hi
hi
```

or some variation thereof which varies proportional to log n.

**Actual output:**

```
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi #15 times, i.e. 2*n-1
```

A few more iterations of this with different input sizes have given me the impression that this is 2*n-1, which makes no sense to me. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: mergesort is O(nlogn), no sorting algorithms can achieve O(n) except the countsort on integers, 2n is just n

Comment: I know, but doesn't the n part come from the while loop? So I thought the function should be called logn times

Comment: It is not true that there are only O(logn) recursive calls. The thing that is O(logn) is the *depth* of the recursion tree, not the number of *nodes* in the recursion tree.

Comment: @trincot that sounds like a start on figuring it out anyway, thanks

Comment: Since the recursion base case is ``if len(my_list) <= 1:``, recursion alone must subdivide the list into at least n sublists of size 1.

Comment: Okay, I think I know what I need to look into now. Thanks everyone

Comment: It might be better to explain merge sort as it was originally implemented and as implemented in most libraries (a hybrid of insertion sort and bottom up merge sort), as a [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation). In this case, the number of passes is ceiling(log2(n)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true that there are only O(logn) recursive calls. The thing that is O(logn) is the *depth* of the recursion tree, not the number of *nodes* in the recursion tree.

When we look at *one* level of the recursion tree, then we can note that each call in *that* level deals with a distinct partition of the array. Together, the "nodes" in that recursion level, deal with all elements of the array, which gives that *level* a O(n) time complexity. This is true for each level.

As there are O(logn) levels, the total complexity comes down to O(nlogn).

Here is a suggestion on how to illustrate this:

```
statistics = []

def merge_sort(my_list, depth=0):
    if len(my_list) <= 1:
        return
    # manage statistics
    if depth >= len(statistics):
        statistics.append(0)  # for each depth we count operations
    mid = len(my_list)//2
    l = my_list[:mid]
    r = my_list[mid:]
    merge_sort(l, depth+1)
    merge_sort(r, depth+1)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    while i < len(l) or j < len(r):
        statistics[depth] += 1  # count this as a O(1) unit of work
        if i >= len(l):
            my_list[k] = r[j]
            j += 1
        elif j >= len(r):
            my_list[k] = l[i]
            i += 1
        elif l[i] < r[j]:
            my_list[k] = l[i]
            i += 1
        elif l[i] > r[j]:
            my_list[k] = r[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

import random

my_list = list(range(32))
random.shuffle(my_list)
merge_sort(my_list)
print(my_list)
print(statistics)
```

The statistics will output the number of units of work done at each level. In the example of an input size of 32, you'll get a list with 5 such numbers.

NB: In Python, `if` conditions don't need parentheses